# My custom class has all the same variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is a simplified example of my problem. I am trying to store the same object with different values. But when I set a new value, all the values change.

StopsOnRoute.h

```
@interface StopsOnRoutes : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger start_route_id;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger start_stop_id;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger start_time;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSMutableArray *route1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     StopsOnRoutes *stopOnRoutes = [[StopsOnRoutes alloc] init];

     int p_time = 0;
     int p_route = 0;
     int p_stop = 0;

     while(p_time<10){

         p_time = p_time + 1;
         p_route = p_route + 1;
         p_stop = p_stop + 1;

         [stopOnRoutes setStart_time:p_time];
         [stopOnRoutes setStart_route_id:p_route];
         [stopOnRoutes setStart_stop_id:p_stop];

         [route1 addObject:stopOnRoutes];
     }
}
```

Unexpected output of array route1:

```
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
10 | 10 | 10
```

Expected output of array route1:

```
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 2
3 | 3 | 3
4 | 4 | 4
5 | 5 | 5
6 | 6 | 6
7 | 7 | 7
8 | 8 | 8
9 | 9 | 9
10 | 10 | 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reusing the same object instance over and over. Create a new one each time in the loop.

```
 while(p_time<10){

     StopsOnRoutes *stopOnRoutes = [[StopsOnRoutes alloc] init];

     p_time = p_time + 1;
     p_route = p_route + 1;
     p_stop = p_stop + 1;

     [stopOnRoutes setStart_time:p_time];
     [stopOnRoutes setStart_route_id:p_route];
     [stopOnRoutes setStart_stop_id:p_stop];

     [route1 addObject:stopOnRoutes];
 }
```